# Table transformation with ranking

Tags: sql, oracle

I've stuck in one moment. I've a table code_table, for example:

```
| code |
--------
| b    |
| c    |
| c    |
| ff   |
| a    |
| f    |
--------
```

But I need in a result like this:

```
| code | id |
-------------
| b    | 2  |
| c    | 3  |
| c    | 3  |
| ff   | 5  |
| a    | 1  |
| f    | 4  |
-------------
```

I suupose, I need to use analytic function like DENSE_RANK(), but my trials didn't get me the needed result. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use it as:

```
select code, dense_rank() over (order by code) as ranking
from t;
```

Your original data does not have any obvious ordering.  This is likely to return the rows in order by `ranking`.  There is no way to recover the original ordering, unless you have a column that specifies that ordering.